# .htaccess Dynamic URL to Static URL

Tags: .htaccess

I have wasted a lot time fixing this issue, now i am turning to get help from experts.:

Issue:

My URLs are dynamically working such as :

`https://www.example.com/services?s=10`

and I want to rewrite, to serve it as following:

`https://www.example.com/services/advanced-biotec-facials`

I have tried following code in htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule services-advanced-biotec-facials$ services?s=10
```

but the urls is becoming:
`https://www.example.com/services-advanced-biotec-facials`

I have also tried following code in htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule services/advanced-biotec-facials$ services?s=10
```

the code is not working with **/services/**

i have copied my htaccess in following txt file for share:

https://www.nrbeauty-dubai.com/share.txt

Please help as I have wasted my time a lot already.

also, I need the old dynamic URL to be redirected to the new rewrite URL.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: its on root. (public_html)

Comment: You're getting 404 for `https://www.example.com/services-advanced-biotec-facials`? Can you show your full .htaccess?

Comment: updated my question. added htaccess file content in txt file to share.

Comment: @FahadBinZafar, could you please post it in your question, links and images are not encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: currently, the url https://www.nrbeauty-dubai.com/advanced-biotec-facials is 200 working. but when i change my htaccess to add /services/ the url https://www.nrbeauty-dubai.com/services/advanced-biotec-facials is not working.

Comment: Try adding `RewriteRule ^services/advanced-biotec-facials/?$ services?s=10 [L,NC,QSA` rule just below `RewriteEngine On` (assuming you have no .htaccess in `services/` directory)

Comment: tried this one. still 500 error when i open the url.

Comment: share.txt file updated for your review.

Comment: For 500 check your error.log conent

Comment: checked the error file. seems not updating.

Answer (score 0):

have u tried swapping them

```
RewriteRule ^services?s=10$ http://www.example.com/services/advanced-biotec-facials/ [R=301,L]
```